# Ready object wrapper class with specific structure

Tags: java, java-8

Short question.

For some purposes, especially in `java-8` with its streams, it is convinient to have some wrapper class like this:

```
class ObjectWrapper<T> {
   T obj;
   boolean set(T obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
      return true;
   }
}
```

it could be nice to use it `stream().filter(...)` conditions to fill up search result with custom objects (different from collections item).

Is any similiar ready class in `java-8`?

---

**EDIT** People ask for usage example. Ok. It is very far-fetched example, but it shows main idea: find first word with odd length and save (return) its length.

```
    List<String> collection = Arrays.asList("ab", "abc3d", "ab", "affdd");

    class ObjectWrapper<T> {
        T obj;
        boolean set(T obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
            return true;
        }
    }

    ObjectWrapper<Integer> oddWordLength = new ObjectWrapper<Integer>();

    collection.stream().filter(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0 && oddWordLength.set(s.length())).findFirst();
```

Comment: Please give example usage.

Comment: sounds like you're searching for stream.map() though your question is pretty unclear

Comment: are you trying to re-invent map function?

Comment: @BoristheSpider look at the edit, please

Comment: @Zielu May be, could you give an example, how to use it instead of my nonsense?

Comment: @BoristheSpider gave you the answer using the map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example:

```
List<String> collection = Arrays.asList("ab", "abc3d", "ab", "affdd");
```

> find first word with odd length and save (return) its length.

A simple solution:

```
return  collection.stream()
                  .filter(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0)
                  .mapToInt(String::length)
                  .findFirst()
```

Note, this will return an `OptionalInt` so that if your `List` is empty it will return `OptionalInt.empty()`.

There is no need for your holder class.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply get the first match (the `String`) and examine its properties afterwards…

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Because of somebody downvoted my question I would like to delete it as rubbish and my mystake. But I can't do that because of your great answer (I'm not able to delete it if answer exists).